# Creating a virtual Bluetooth interface for an SPP connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

I'm new to Android development and i have a task to develop an application that suppose to catch Bluetooth barcode scanner SNs then calling some API for verification then pass the SN if valid to third-party application that expect a Bluetooth scanner SN.
I think i need to perform kind of Man In The Middle between the Bluetooth barcode scanner and the third-party application.
In windows I use for those kind of tasks a virtual serial port to forward the data back to the third-part app. In android case i don't know how to start. Can anyone help me please.